# Group commute properties

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group

If $y\in G$ commutes with some $x\in G$ then $y$ commutes with powers of $x$ i.e $yx^n =x^ny$.

I know this is true but is the other way around true?

If $y\in G$ commutes with a power of some $x\in G$ say $x^n$ then $y$ commutes with $x$ i.e $yx=xy$

Comment: This is not true. Consider the dihedral group for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $n$ be the order of $x$. You know $yx^n=ye=y=ey=x^ny$, but in general it's not true that $xy=xy$.

Answer (score 3):

Nope: Every non-abelian finite group produces counterexamples to this; if $|G| = n$, then the fact that $x^n = e$ for all $y \in G$ implies that

$$yx^n = x^n y$$

In fact, this gives counterexamples in every group where there is a non-central element of finite order.